# Calling AWS API Gateway using IAM Roles

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an API Gateway that I have been calling from Node.js using the aws4 library using this format:

```
let aws4 = require('aws4');

let request = {
  host: 'myapi.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://myapi.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Prod/foos',
  path: '/Prod/foos'
}

let signedRequest = aws4.sign(request,
  {
    secretAccessKey: AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey,
    accessKeyId: AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId
  })

delete signedRequest.headers['Host']
delete signedRequest.headers['Content-Length']

let response = await axios(signedRequest)
```

Now, we want to stop saving the credentials directly on the server and use IAM Roles instead.

When I try calling it without the credentials, regardless of whether it is signed using aws4, I get this error:

```
The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

Comment: Perhaps: [mhart/aws4: Signs and prepares node.js (and browser) requests using AWS Signature Version 4](https://github.com/mhart/aws4)

Comment: That's the library I'm using. I'm trying to figure if its possible to use it without passing in credentials

Comment: Yes. Simply don't provide credentials (as shown on that page). It will automatically retrieve it from the IAM Role assigned to the EC2 instance.

Comment: I'm getting "The security token included in the request is invalid" when I try that